# Trinidad <tr:poll tag

Tags: jsp, jsf, trinidad

JSF / Trinidad

JSF 1.2-1.2_07-b03-FCS

JSTL 1_1-mr2 (special build)

Trinidad 1.2.8

Java 1.6.0_22-b04

Eclipse 3.6.0 (Helios)

Tomcat 6.0.28 (needs to run also on Weblogic)

IE 7.0.5730.13

Firefox: 6.0

Modest experience in JSF, less with Trinidad.

I have my first Trinidad (partially) program working.
Desire to add polling.

JSP file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" prefix="tr"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html" prefix="trh"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<!-- other stuff -->
    <tr:form>
        <tr:poll 
            interval="5000" 
            id="poller" 
            pollListener="#{freqViewTable.getExecutePoll}">
        </tr:poll>
<!-- other stuff -->
    </tr:form>
```

The form is properly displayed.
After 5 seconds (the poll time), a popup box is displayed:

Error
A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?
Line: 14875
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Selecting "Yes" to the Debug question locks everything.
Selecting "No" allows the form to proceed, but (no surprise) no updates.

This also happens when it is tried with no attributes (after 5 seconds - the default).

Note, the JSF, JSTL, Trinidad jar files are part of a commercial licensed product, which we would have difficulty changing, unless absolutely required.

So the question is: do I appear to have a defective Trinidad fileset, an additional tag library is required, or something else?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am just taking a wild guess here, as no body seems to be interested in answering this question, what is the signature of the function getExecutePoll, did you make sure it is

```
public void getExecutePoll(PollEvent pe)
```

Comment: I was building/testing in an Eclipse IDE environment and had done everything right.  Discussion with the vendor of the Trinidad version being used, yielded no solution.  I then, just for a test, built a .war file and did an install to Apache.  It worked.  Note, I had never had a discrepancy between the Eclipse IDE and an actual build as far as the operation of components and tags.  Thus the final answer is:  it does not work in the Eclipse IDE test environment, but does work in a real build.  Thus, the situation is OK, at least for now.  However, thank you for your suggestion.  John